# Completing a set of orthonormal vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, orthonormal, gram-schmidt

Suppose that I have an orthonormal set of vectors
$$ \left\{{\bf v}_1, {\bf v}_2, \dots, {\bf v}_k \right\}  \subset \mathbb{R}^n, $$
where $k < n$. How can I use Gram-Schmidt orthonormalisation process to introduce the remaining vectors to have an orthonormal set which spans the entire space $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: sure thing, you need to pick a completing basis first though. I.e. a basis $\{u_1,...,u_n\}$ such that $u_i=v_i$ for $1\le i\le k$. This will give an orthonormal basis after applying Gram Schmidt. Gram Schmidht needs a set of linearly independent vectors as input though!

Comment: Yes, but how can I find such a basis $\left\{u_1, \dots, u_n \right\}$?

Comment: @mathslover pick one vector of $\mathbb{R}^n$ at random. The probability that it will be in the subspace spanned by the $k$ vectors you already have is zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run [the Gram–Schmidt process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) for $\{{\bf v}_1, {\bf v}_2, \dots, {\bf v}_k, {\bf s}_1, {\bf s}_2, \cdots, {\bf s}_n\}$, where ${\bf s}_1=(1,0,0,\cdots, 0)$, ${\bf s}_2=(0,1,0\cdots, 0)$, etc. is the standard basis of $\Bbb R^n$. However, whenever you find some ${\bf u}_i=0$, discard it. (The first $k$ steps are trivial, since ${\bf v}_1, {\bf v}_2, \dots, {\bf v}_k$ are orthonormal.)

Or you can use any $n$ linearly independent vectors instead of the standard basis.

Or as CyclotomicField suggested, "you can pick one vector $\bf r$ of $\Bbb R^n$ at random". Compute $${\bf r}_p={\bf r}-\sum _{i=1}^{j}\operatorname {proj} _{{\bf v}_j}({\bf r}),$$
where ${\bf v}_1,{\bf v}_2,\cdots, {\bf v}_j$ are the orthonormal vectors obtained so far, $j\ge k$.  Repeat until you got ${\bf r}_p\not=0$. Then set ${\bf v}_{j+1}=\frac {{\bf r}_p}{\|{\bf r}_p\|}$, extending the orthonormal vectors by another one. Repeat until we have $n$ orthonormal vectors.

Comment: In this standard basis approach, how can you be sure that in the end you have $n$ vectors?